# box2d body isn't moving

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

so, I've something like this:

```
physicsWorld=new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(10, 10), false);
Rectangle test = new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50, vbom);

FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0f, 0.5f);

Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, test, BodyType.DynamicBody, wallFixtureDef);
physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(test, body));
body.setLinearVelocity(100, 100);

registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);

attachChild(test);
```

and it doesn't work, body isn't moving. 
Any ideas why?

GLES 2 AnchorCenter

Comment: Are you stepping the world?

Comment: what do you mean by "stepping the world" 

if "I'm updating my scene" yes I'm in here:
registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);

Answer (score 0):

your physicsworld register to your game scene.
it work my device and body is moving.

```
    PhysicsWorld physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(10, 10), false);
    Rectangle test = new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory
            .createFixtureDef(0, 0f, 0.5f);
    Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, test,
            BodyType.DynamicBody, wallFixtureDef);
    physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(test, body));
    body.setLinearVelocity(100, 100);
    yourScene.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);
    yourScene.attachChild(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my view you have to apply two changes in you code.

1. Change Physics world constructor value in the following way

   mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0,SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH),false);
2. Change PhysicsConnector as per the following way

   new PhysicsConnector(test,body,true,true);

I think second suggestion work for you because in your code I see you does not update position as well as rotation for your object.